# Battery life reduced after upgrade to kernel 4.4.8 (16.04 LTS)

Tags: kernel, power-management, 16.04, battery

UPDATE: I have elaborated more on the problem in another post. [Read it here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767728/poor-battery-life-kernel-4-5-2-tlp-energy-perf-policy-not-installed-16-04-lt)

**EDIT**: Upgrading to 4.5.2 stable does the same thing. Is it the AMDGPU using more resources? How can I disable, I care more about battery life, and power-saving GPU.

**EDIT 2:** at 4.5.2 HDMI works perfectly, 4.4.0 didn't. Since HDMI is probably attached to AMDGPU, is there a way to disable it and still use HDMI?

I upgraded from 4.4.0 kernel to 4.4.8 due to unability to suspend/hybernate my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Lenovo z51-70 and now it would seem my battery life has somehow halved. I used to be able to have 2.5 hours on average, now as soon as I plug out, the battery indicator shows 1.27 h. I have not installed any new software. How can I notice what's causing the draining?

**Here's the relative output. TLP:**

```
System         = LENOVO Lenovo Z51-70 80K6
BIOS           = C2CN19WW(V2.00)
Release        = Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Kernel         = 4.4.8-040408-generic #201604200335 SMP Wed Apr 20 07:37:30 UTC 2016 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-040408-generic root=UUID=0739d2c4-9774-41f4-bd8c-b7bd3ee7c53c ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Init system    = systemd

+++ System Status
TLP power save = enabled
power source   = battery

+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = LENOVO 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = PABAS0241231
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design             =  31680 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full                    =  25220 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now                     =  23000 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now                      =  16627 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Discharging
```

**Here's the powertop output:**

[image]

This didn't happen at kernel 4.4.0 nor at 14.04 LTS

**EDIT:** Maybe relevant, I'm using hybrid-graphics (Intel power-saving, ATI discreet GPU, but I Intel's is being used, as per lspci VGA controller)

Should I upgrade to the latest stable kernel? Downgrade? Any advice?

Comment: I heard support for ATI cards is not that great currently - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04