# Poorer battery life after kernel upgrade: 4.5.2 (16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery, amd-graphics, tlp

When I first installed 16.04 LTS, at kernel 4.4.0, I had a decent battery life of about **3 hours average**, but I **upgraded to 4.5.2** to solve the suspend problem and some other issues, and now it's less than **1.40 hours**, even at low brightness.

What could have caused a drop between the kernels? 4.5.2 is stable, and the same thing happened when upgrading to 4.4.8 (lts).

I'm attaching TLP outputs. I'm desperate to make this a better battery life.

uname -a:

```
Linux gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 4.5.2-040502-generic #201604200335 SMP Wed Apr 20 07:37:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I did a **tlp -stat output** of both kernels in use (4.4.0 and 4.5.2), and the only difference I can notice is that the latest kernel 4.5.2, outputs this, compared to the 4.4.0 which saves battery:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      = 18
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          = 0

x86_energy_perf_policy: program for your kernel not installed.
```

When I try to install linux-tools, as explained at [TLP's troubleshooting website](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html), which says

```
tlp-stat -p shows "x86_energy_perf_policy: program [for your kernel] not installed."

Depending on the distro your mileage may vary:

Ubuntu: install the meta-package linux-tools (or linux-tools-lts-* for HWE stack kernels), no package available for mainline kernels.
```

I get:

```
 Package linux-tools is a virtual package provided by:
      linux-tools-virtual 4.4.0.21.22
      linux-tools-lowlatency 4.4.0.21.22
      linux-tools-generic 4.4.0.21.22
    You should explicitly select one to install.
```

So no tools for 4.5.2 kernel. Or should I install HWE stack tools? What does HWE mean in relation to the stable 4.5.2 kernel?

Many thanks.

**EDIT**: At 4.5.2 I can also hear the fan more frequently and intensely, even at opening Chrome, Skype, etc.

**EDIT 2**: It might be worth noting that I use a hybrid graphics system INtel and ATI, but I haven't installed any propriertary drivers, or manually upgraded any.

**EDIT 3**: sudo tail -f -n 1000 /var/log/syslog when starting TLP:

```
^[[B^[[AMay  5 21:52:57 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 7945.966502] acpi_call: Cannot get handle: Error: AE_NOT_FOUND
May  5 21:52:57 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 7945.976707] acpi_call: Cannot get handle: Error: AE_NOT_FOUND
May  5 21:53:12 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 7961.360242] acpi_call: Cannot get handle: Error: AE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: If using dual graphics ati/intel then you may want to look at ubuntu's own troubleshooting page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Comment: Did you install the 4.5.2 kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, the problem was that in dual graphics system, the newer kernels would load both the power-saving and discreet GPU, whereas the default install kernel that came with 16.04 LTS would not, and subsequently the fan and battery would be drained more.

This could have been solved by creating and using a radeonoff script when booting, or simply, as I solved it, disabling the switichable graphics options in BIOS. Temporary solution, untilAMDGPU is more developed.

Comment: Excuse me, Mookey, would you mind describing how you accomplished this?

Comment: F12 when booting computer, enter BIOS and find the Graphics options, and it should state sth like Switchable graphics or UMI graphics, so choose the latter.

Answer (score 3):

You have installed `TLP` to extend the battery life on your laptop, but are still getting poor battery life.  When you look at the output of `tlp -stat output` you found the error message `x86_energy_perf_policy: program for your kernel not installed`.

When you attempt to install the energy performance policy by `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic` the install appears to work but does not have any effect.

I have looked at the code for `x86_energy_perf_policy` and I could see no issues with it. It does not appear to be kernel specific so it looks like `x86_energy_perf_policy` which is part of `linux-tools-common` is not linked into the kernel properly.

This will have a big effect on battery life for laptops with Intel CPUs since the default policy is to maximise performance at the expense of energy expenditure (and hence battery life).

I may be wrong and `x86_energy_perf_policy` could be depreciated and `TLP` has yet to catch up but this looks like a serious kernel bug. I could attempt to patch your kernel to resolve this, but this issue will effect this and subsequent versions of the Linux kernel until it is resolved so I suggest you raise a bug by entering `ubuntu-bug` at a terminal. Feel free to paste parts of this answer into your bug report if this helps.

Comment: I have, but it's valid for version 4.4.0.22. Not 4.5.2. Can I somehow compile or make it valid?

Comment: The command i included in the answer will install the version of linux-tools valid for your kernel

Comment: It installed the tools for kernel 4.4.0, and still, not the perf tool.

Comment: Run the command again and paste the entire dialog into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it so I can see what is going on.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/16317992/

Comment: OK. Now run `sudo apt-get update` and paste the entire results of that. Respond with `n` to the suggested changes so I can check you are not going to delete anything vital.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39507/discussion-between-mookey-and-steve-roome).

Comment: DO NOT file a bug report on this kernel; it is unofficial and your bug report will just be marked as invalid.